# Why does the mock()->makePartial() function doesn't work in a fluent chain?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, mockery

Why does the `mock()->makePartial()` function need to be called on a separate line? What am I missing?

This works:

```
$mock = Mockery::mock()->makePartial();
$mock->shouldReceive(123);
```

This doesn't work:

```
$mock = Mockery::mock()->makePartial()
  ->shouldReceive(123);
```

phpunit returns an error for test_chained:

> TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, class Mockery\Expectation does not have a method "setTime"

Answer (score 0):

The two code snippets are not semantically equivalent. In the first one you assign a `Mock` to `$mock` (the return value of `::mock()`) and in the second an `Expectation` (the return value of `shouldReceive()`). Therefore, when calling `$mock->setTime()` in the second case, you are not calling `setTime()` on the mock object, but you are trying to call it on the `Expectation`. (Please mind that this contains a lot of guesswork, since you seem not to have presented all of the relevant code parts.)

Comment: Thanks Eric!
`makePartial()` and `shouldReceive()` work differently, they return different types.
`makePartial()` is intended to modify the whole `Mock` object, it returns `$this`.
`shouldReceive()` just adds another expectation routine, it returns the new expectation routine object so that we can modify it, but not the whole `Mock` object.